# how to remove specific element from 2D Array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have a `[[String]]` like

`myArr = [["1_2","1_3","1_4"], ["2_1","2_2","2_3"], ["3_1","3_2","3_3"]]` then

I Want to remove element like this
`bypassArr = ["1_2","2_3","3_2"`]

how to remove `bypassArr` from `myArr` using element. or how can i get this type of result.

`result = [["1_3","1_4"], ["2_1","2_2"], ["3_1","3_3"]]`

Comment: Show your attempt, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the intention is to remove all elements from `bypassArr` in the “inner” arrays from `myArr` then a combination of `map()` and `filter()` does the trick:

```
let myArr = [["1_2","1_3","1_4"], ["2_1","2_2","2_3"], ["3_1","3_2","3_3"]]
let bypassArr = ["1_2","2_3","3_2"]

let result = myArr.map { innerArray in
    innerArray.filter { elem in
        !bypassArr.contains(elem)
    }
}

print(result)
// [["1_3", "1_4"], ["2_1", "2_2"], ["3_1", "3_3"]]
```

The inner arrays are *filtered* to remove the given elements, and the outer array is *mapped* to the filtered results.

Or with short-hand parameter notation:

```
let result = myArr.map { $0.filter { !bypassArr.contains($0) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArr = [["1_2","1_3","1_4"], ["2_1","2_2","2_3"], ["3_1","3_2","3_3"]]
let bypassArr = ["1_2","2_3","3_2"]
if myArr.count == bypassArr.count {
    myArr = bypassArr.enumerated().map({ (index, str) -> [String] in
        if let strPos = myArr[index].firstIndex(of: str) {
            myArr[index].remove(at: strPos)
        }
        return myArr[index]
    })
}
print(myArr)
```

Comment: Result is = [["1_3", "1_4"], ["2_1", "2_2", "2_3"], ["3_1", "3_2", "3_3"]] but not remove "2_3" and 3_2 on your result

Comment: Thanks for trying @RajeshKumar but when i Remove  let bypassArr = ["1_2","2_1","2_3","3_2"] like then result is wrong.

Comment: I performed the action only if both array counts are same

Comment: ok but my count is different.

Comment: What problem you have with Martin R's answer?